# where can I set that libpcap library in Mac/XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, pcap, libpcap

the linker returns:
Ld Build/Products/Debug/PCap normal x86_64
    cd ~/PCap
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.\
    xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/\
    Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk \
    -L~/PCap/Build/Products/Debug -F~/PCap/Build/Products/Debug -filelist \
    ~/PCap/Build/Intermediates/PCap.build/Debug/PCap.build/Objects-normal\
    /x86_64/PCap.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 \
    -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker \
    ~/PCap/Build/Intermediates/PCap.build/Debug/PCap.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/PCap_lto.o \
    -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker \
    -dependency_info -Xlinker ~/PCap/Build/Intermediates/PCap.build/Debug/PCap.build/Objects-normal\
    /x86_64/PCap_dependency_info.dat -o ~/PCap/Build/Products/Debug/PCap

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pcap_compile", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_pcap_findalldevs", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_pcap_lookupnet", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_pcap_loop", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_pcap_open_live", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_pcap_setfilter", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I think - he is missing that library. But which name? The finder can't find anything as 'pcap'. 
If I install libpcap with brew, I got: cap already installed.
And brew: macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
Has someone used pcap on Mac/OS X? And can help? 
I have reduced my source to a very small example - but got this errors...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to link the pcap by using -lpcap. Then it should work.